# CSS TranslationX of container not working in Safari

Tags: safari, css-transitions, css-transforms

Today I have noticed a weird behavior of Safari (9.0) when **I applied a transition to an element that was translating on the X axis while the width was also increasing**.

I have reproduced the behavior in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epigeyre/k5e2a0by/2/). Here is an embed code for those who like it better. In Firefox and Chrome it looks pretty smooth but not in Safari, **does anyone have a solution or a best way to achieve the same effect**?

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
 container = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    
button.addEventListener('click', function() { container.classList.toggle('open'); });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: width 1s, transform 1s;
}
.open ul {
  width: 200%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
li {
  /* Just some style first */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1em 0;
  
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
li:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button">Toggle translation</button>
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure if you would be interested in JS-based solutions instead of pure CSS and if you would be willing to explore this animation library called **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap)**. **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/L88kjnjc/)** is a solution using `TweenMax` which I believe works pretty well across all browsers. And quite honestly, I am not sure what `TweenMax` does behind the scenes (and not interested either :D) as long as it delivers a consistent result, which it has been for many years for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TahirAhmed! I will choose a JS-based solution if nobody can offer an answer in pure css. The JS solution has to be as light as possible and in pure js (no jQuery but I accept libraries such as GSAP or Dynamics).

Comment: Makes sense. Let me know if you have questions about GSAP. I will gladly share what I know.

Comment: @TahirAhmed Can you post your GSAP solution as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-posting as an answer.

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/L88kjnjc/)** is the jsFiddle result and snippet as below:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var container = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var timeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
timeline.to('ul', 1, { width: '200%', xPercent: -50, ease: Power2.easeInOut });

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 timeline.progress() > 0 ? timeline.reverse() : timeline.play();
});
```

```css
.container {
 width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  display: block;
 width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 0;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
li:first-child {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button">Toggle translation</button>
```

Hope this is helpful.

P.S. I have been using GSAP for quite a while now and I don't remember getting stuck on any browser-specific issues unless a browser would do something differently. A little research into GSAP and it would tell you that browser compatibility is one of their main selling points.

Comment: I have chosen your answer because I ended up using GSAP for some animations. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

By animating `margin-left` instead of `translateX` the result is acceptable in Safari:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
  container = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 container.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.container {
 width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: width 1s, margin-left 1s;
}
.open ul {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left:-100%;
}
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  
 display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 0;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
li:first-child {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button">Toggle translation</button>
```

Using `scaleX` instead of animating `width` is smoother, but probably not what you want.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
  container = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 container.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.container {
 width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  display: block;
 width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.open ul {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(2);
}
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  
 display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 0;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
li:first-child {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button">Toggle translation</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By animating `margin-left` the result is correct but in terms of performance and logic (this is design-y motion) I would rather use `translate()`. The `scale()` option doesn't work as the text gets stretched.

Comment: in terms of performance, also the animation of `width` is not a good idea. maybe you should use only `scale` and `translate`. Then you have to get out the text and translate it too.

Comment: This is true. That will make the code a bit longer but this is probably the best way to do it with CSS (if I care about performance). In terms of using this animation in real work production, in most cases I kind of feel like it would be better to just use a dedicated javascript library like GSAP or Dynamics (less debugging but as efficient as CSS transform).

Answer (score 0):

So, I will try to sum up the two best solutions here : one with CSS transform and the other with Javascript animation (GSAP).

---

### CSS TRANSFORM

In terms of performance, it is recommended to only animate transforms (translate, scale, rotate) and opacity. If you are interested in more optimisation details you can [have a look at this article by Anna Migas](http://blog.lunarlogic.io/2016/boost-your-css-animation-performance-with-repaintless-css).

So, as @Meiko suggested, the best solution is to only animate scale and translate properties. Here is a code sample ([and the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epigeyre/wr7sreLs/8/))

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
  container = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.classList.toggle('open');
})
```

```css
.container,
ul {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* reset default browser styles */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  
  /* Just some style */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

li:first-child::before {
  background-color: green;
}

.open li:first-child {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.open li:nth-of-type(2)::before {
  transform: scaleX(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button">Toggle translation</button>
```

**PROS:**

- Only use a tiny bit of Javascript to toggle class,
- The browser support is quite good (needs vendor-specific properties and some testing),
- Really fast and light on GPU memory.

**CONS:**

- Pretty limited in terms of usage (the actual width of the second cell stays the same),
- Needs more lines of CSS.

---

### JS ANIMATION (WITH GSAP)

This solution has been suggested by @Tahir Ahmed and use the [GSAP library](http://greensock.com/gsap). As a side note, I really think that this is the best js library out there for this kind of animation. Here is a snippet of how it works ([and the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epigeyre/6hnbwzLc/5/)):

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
  timeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
  
timeline.to('ul', 1, { width: '200%', xPercent: -50 });

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  timeline.progress() > 0 ? timeline.reverse() : timeline.play();
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  
  /* reset default browser styles */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  background-color: red;
  
  /* Just some style */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

li:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button type="button">Toggle translation</button>
```

**PROS:**

- Really flexible, sky is the limit!
- You can animate properties such as `display` (you can't in CSS),
- Compatible with every browser out there (down to IE6).

**CONS:**

- Require a third party library (about 30kb),
- Seems a bit harder for the GPU (although it needs more testing to be sure).

---

In the end it really depends on the animation you need but if it get's a little bit more complex than moving a container around then I will choose GSAP.